# Erro ao integrar uma função real

Tags: r, integração

estou tentando integrar, sob toda a reta, a função:

```
integrand_1<-function(x){
  exp(-x/phi-y*exp(-x)/(phi*2)-(x+sigma2/2)^2/(2*sigma2))}
```

Usando os seguintes dados:

```
df <- readRDS(url("https://rawcdn.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/db2ff43778b047eab9761cdedb16f70a08ec2f89/df.rds"))
phi <- 0.02216155
rho <- 0.6003019
sigma2 <- 0.02652626
y <- df$y
mu <- df$mu
```

Para isso, uso a função integrate, conforme abaixo:

```
integrate(Vectorize(integrand_1), -Inf, Inf)$value
```

No entanto, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Error in integrate(Vectorize(integrand_1), -Inf, Inf) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

Tentei visualizar a função para ver se havia algo errado,
usando esse código:

```
x <- seq(-10,10, length=300)
integrand_1(x)
is.numeric(integrand_1(x))
plot(x,integrand_1(x), xlim = c(2.3,2.6), type = "l")
```

O gráfico gerado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, não era para gerar o erro acima. Ou pelo menos não entendo
o motivo do erro. Alguém, poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função `integrate` é definida como

> Adaptive quadrature of functions of one variable over a finite or infinite interval

Em particular, veja como ela define o integrando `f` (grifos meus):

> an R function taking a **numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length**. Returning a non-finite element will generate an error.

A função definida em `integrand_1` possui `y` em sua definição, além de `x`. Dessa forma, ao entrar algum valor `x` de uma dimensão, ela retorna uma resposta com tamanho igual a `y`, que nesse caso específico é 300:

```
integrand_1 <- function(x){
  exp(-x/phi-y*exp(-x)/(phi*2)-(x+sigma2/2)^2/(2*sigma2))
}

integrand_1(0)

  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [77] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[115] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[153] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[191] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[229] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[267] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Portanto, reveja se `y` precisa mesmo ser informado como um vetor para `integrand_1`. Talvez `integrate` não seja a função adequada para resolver este problema, pois ele tem a maior cara de ser algo multivariado.

Comment: Oi Prof. Marcus Nunes, de fato você tem razão, o y é um vetor. Estava acreditando que isso não deveria ser um problema para o cálculo. Vou ver o que faço! Obrigado